# Python Beautiful Soup. only returning 1st row of table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Just learning Python & Beautiful soup.   Trying to scrape River Water Flows from a number of sites. Had success with most of the sites, but one in particular is giving me problems.
The site is http://hydro.marlborough.govt.nz/reports/riverreport.html.   I'm trying to get the 24th row of data from the main table.

The below seems to select the table but only returns the header & first row.

```
tMain_table = soup.select_one("table:nth-of-type(1)")

print (tMain_table)
```

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead style="background-color: #4d4c4f;color: white;">
    <tr>
    <th class="text-center">Site Name</th>
    <th class="text-center"><div>Date/Time </div>(NZST)</th>
    <th class="text-center"><div>Flow</div>(m3/s)</th>
    <th class="text-center" nowrap="nowrap"><div>7 Day</div>Peak Flow</th>
    <th class="text-center"><div>Stage</div>(m)</th>
    <th class="text-center"><div>Change</div>(mm/hr)</th>
    <th class="text-center" nowrap="nowrap"><div>7 Day </div>Peak Stage</th>
    <th class="text-center"><div>Peak</div>Date/Time</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in data ">
    <td nowrap="nowrap">{{item.SiteName}}</td>
    <td class="text-center" nowrap="nowrap">{{item.LastUpdate | asDate | date:'d MMM yy         HH:mm'}} </td>
    <td class="text-center" nowrap="nowrap">{{item.Flow}}</td>
    <td class="text-center" nowrap="nowrap">{{item.PeakFlow}}</td>
    <td class="text-center" nowrap="nowrap">{{item.Stage}}</td>
    <td class="text-center" nowrap="nowrap">{{item.StageChange}}</td>
    <td class="text-center" nowrap="nowrap">{{item.PeakStage}}</td>
    <td class="text-center" nowrap="nowrap">{{item.PeakStageDate | asDate | date:'d MMM yy HH:mm'}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Likewise the below also only returns the first row.

```
table = soup.findAll('tr')

print (table)
```

```
    [<tr>
    <th class="text-center">Site Name</th>
    <th class="text-center"><div>Date/Time </div>(NZST)</th>
    <th class="text-center"><div>Flow</div>(m3/s)</th>
    <th class="text-center" nowrap="nowrap"><div>7 Day</div>Peak Flow</th>
    <th class="text-center"><div>Stage</div>(m)</th>
    <th class="text-center"><div>Change</div>(mm/hr)</th>
    <th class="text-center" nowrap="nowrap"><div>7 Day </div>Peak Stage</th>
    <th class="text-center"><div>Peak</div>Date/Time</th>
    </tr>, <tr ng-repeat="item in data ">
    <td nowrap="nowrap">{{item.SiteName}}</td>
    <td class="text-center" nowrap="nowrap">{{item.LastUpdate | asDate | date:'d MMM yy HH:mm'}} </td>
    <td class="text-center" nowrap="nowrap">{{item.Flow}}</td>
    <td class="text-center" nowrap="nowrap">{{item.PeakFlow}}</td>
    <td class="text-center" nowrap="nowrap">{{item.Stage}}</td>
    <td class="text-center" nowrap="nowrap">{{item.StageChange}}</td>
    <td class="text-center" nowrap="nowrap">{{item.PeakStage}}</td>
    <td class="text-center" nowrap="nowrap">{{item.PeakStageDate | asDate | date:'d MMM yy HH:mm'}} 
    </td>
    </tr>]
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: The web site HTML only has one row. The site adds more rows dynamically with JavaScript.

Comment: Use `View Source` in the browser to see what you're processing.

Comment: The site uses AngularJS.

Comment: Hi @Barmar , do you know how to process systematically (in pure python) such js-pages? Should one use a js-parser to build an AST or there are better strategies?

Comment: Use Selenium WebDriver to execute the JavaScript.

Comment: but in a DIY approach? Does make sense working with AST?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.   As noted I'm a bit of a newbee for this, so some examples of how I would achieve this in Python would be really great.

Answer (score 1):

A webpage with dynamic content can be rendered, *for example*, with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/)

A minimal example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = # 

with webdriver.Firefox() as driver: # there are other drivers available
   driver = webdriver.Firefox()
   # driver.implicitly_wait(10)

   rendered_wpage = driver.get(url).page_source
   
soup = BeautifulSoup(rendered_wpage, 'lxml')
# scrape here
```

Comment: selenium is quite intuitive and well documented but it is NOT designed for scraping but for web browser automation which means has some limitations (file downloads, ...)

Comment: All Sorted.  After a bit of time to get Selenium up and running, I can no retrieve the data I need.    Many thanks for the Help.

Comment: Hi @Barmar.  I've had a lot of success following your suggestion of using Selenium.  have now got almost all the data from the sites I need.   However one more site is posing problems.   http://envdata.es.govt.nz/?tab=table  I need to get the data from the table on the right.  I can see all the data when using Inspect, but rendering the page through Selenium does not seem to include that table.  Any suggestions?